# Doubt regarding the current in the Franck-Hertz experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In the [Franck-Hertz experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franck%E2%80%93Hertz_experiment), the current between the cathode and the anode increases when the accelerating voltage is increased until the mercury atoms in the tube get excited and then the current decreases. However, if the accelerating voltage keeps being increased, the current increases until the mercury atoms get excited again, and so on, with voltage peaks getting higher and higher each time. I understand that the current increases due to the fact that the electrons are accelerated more as the voltage is increased, so they get to the anode faster. However, I feel that doesn't still change the number of electrons that get to the anode per unit of time (current), so how come can the current be increased? The only way I see this could happen would be if the cathode released more electrons per minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cathode electron current is a space-charge limited current and increases with the positive voltage of the grid approximately according to a 3/2 power law (Langmuir-Child's law). Therefore the number of electrons that can participate in the inelastic collisions and transmission to the anode producing the anode current increases with positive grid voltage. (The anode current is a only a very small fraction of the total cathode current.) This leads to the peaks (and valleys) in the anode current increasing with the grid voltage.